# if condition in password verify condition is not working properly in php

Tags: php, mysql

HI Guys i am trying to verify one condition in my login page that is if my password is **change me** then i would like to throw error message saying that please change your password by clicking this link if not i will redirect them to dashboard.

So i wrote if condition for that but what will happen is it is throwing error message if password is not **change me** also

Here is my code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

        global $DB;

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        echo $password;
        //exit;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {user}  where username = ?";

        if ($user = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, array($username))) {
            echo $user->password;
            //exit;
            if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
                if(password_verify($password!='changeme',$user->password!='changeme')){
                  if ($user->trackforums == 1) {
                    complete_user_login($user);
                    \core\session\manager::apply_concurrent_login_limit($user->id, session_id());
                    $userauth = get_auth_plugin($USER->auth);

                    $DB->set_field('user', 'firstaccess', date('YmdHis'), array('id' => $user->id));
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user->firstname;
                    $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $user->idnumber;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id;
                    $_SESSION['clientid'] = $user->clientid;
                    $_SESSION['maildigest'] = $user->maildigest;
                    $_SESSION['skype'] = $user->skype;
                    $_SESSION['can_access'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['mnethostid'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION['confirmed'] = 1;

                    if (!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                        setcookie("member_login", $_POST["username"], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                        setcookie("password", $_POST["password"], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
                            setcookie("member_login", "");
                        }
                        if (isset($_COOKIE["password"])) {
                            setcookie("password", "");
                        }
                    }

                    if ($user->idnumber == '3')
                        header('location:course.php');
                    elseif ($user->idnumber == '2')
                        header('location:course.php');
                    else
                        header('location:course.php');
                }

                else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong> Sorry, User has been Deactivated. Contact Administrator</strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
                else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-primary">
                        <strong>Please change your password!By clicking this link <a style="color:black" href="forgot-password.php">Click Here</a></strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong> Sorry, wrong password.</strong>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong> Sorry, wrong username.</strong>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me what is the mistake in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `(password_verify($password!='changeme',$user->password!='changeme'))` ?

Comment: if password is change me i would show error message if not  redirect them to dahsboard

Comment: i mean in that specific `if` statement, you're using wrong `password_verify` function

Comment: oh okay sorry i dont have that much idea of using password_verify function

Comment: This looks hell'a unsecure... Don't put the plaintext password in a cookie x.x You need to catch up on 20 years of security.

Comment: ok what will be the security for that can you please explain me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) takes both parameter as `string`, not as `bool`. You are passing them as `bool` in second `password_verify`. In following line, `$password != 'changeme'` & `$user->password != 'changeme'`, both expressions will return `bool`.

```
if (password_verify($password != 'changeme', $user->password != 'changeme'))
```

I think, the above line code should be like:

```
if ($password != 'changeme')
```